# KGet not starting

Tags: 16.04

I run KGet and it doesn't startup. When I run it on the terminal, I get this message:

```
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
    KGlobal::locale(): Warning your global KLocale is being recreated with a valid main component instead of a fake component, this usually means you tried to call i18n related functions before your main component was created. You should not do that since it most likely will not work
    QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
   QWidget::insertAction: Attempt to insert null action
    QWidget::insertAction: Attempt to insert null action
    user@Aspire-One-753:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by running `mv ~/.kde ~/.kde.bak` to reset the configuration and now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and setting `EnableSystemTray=false` in `~/.config/kgetrc` solved the problem for now.